# How to replace part of a regex with sed?

Tags: regex, sed

In a file `test.txt` I have the following text line

```
COPYRIGHT (c) 2020 alex4200
```

in which I want to use `sed` to find that line and to replace the year `2020` by the year `2021`. I have tried the following expression:

```
sed -i -E  "s/COPYRIGHT .*(\d\{4\}) alex4200/2021/" test.txt
```

but it did not change the text in the file `test.txt`. What am I missing?

Comment: You are searching for a literal `{`, which is not present in your string. Also, `\d` has no special meaning in a [POSIX regular ](https://www.regular-expressions.info/posix.html), not even in _extended_ POSIX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing first `\d` is not supported in `sed` you need to use `[0-9]`. Then your expression is also not correct(even you fix `\d` it will not work with your tried code), so I have corrected it as per your shown samples. With your shown samples, please try following.

```
sed -E 's/^([^ ]* +[^ ]*) +([^\s]*) +(.*)$/\1 2021 \3/' Input_file
```

Once you are happy with results(which will be shown on terminal) you can use `-i` option to do inplace save in above code.

***Explanation:*** Simple explanation would be, using `sed`'s backreference capability while substitution. In first part of substitution part, making 3 back references as per shown samples, where 2nd back reference will have 2020 value in it, while doing substitution putting 2021 value there.

***Explanation of regex:***

```
^([^ ]* +[^ ]*)  ##From starting of value creating 1st back reference which will match values just before 2nd occurrence of space.
 +               ##Matching 1 or more occurrences of spaces here.
([^\s]*)         ##Creating 2nd capturing group which will match everything till space comes, to catch 2020 basically.
 +               ##Matching 1 or more occurrences of spaces here.
(.*)$            ##Matching everything till last here and creating 3rd back reference here.
```

***Fixing OP's attempts:***

```
sed -E  's/^(COPYRIGHT .*\(c\))\s+([^ ]*)\s+(.*)/\1 2021 \3/' Input_file
```

OR to match digits with shown samples, following could be used:

```
sed -E 's/^(COPYRIGHT\s+\(.*\))\s+([0-9]{4})(.*)$/\1 2021 \3/' Input_file
```

Comment: I want to change the content of the file `test.txt`. Maybe you misunderstood my question?

Comment: @Alex, I have added a note about `-i` once you are Good with my code, which will print on terminal you can use `-i` option to do inplace save into Input_file.

Comment: The text I want to search and replace is in a file, not in an echo statement. So I have to do something like `echo `cat test.txt` | sed -i -E 's/^([^ ]* +[^ ]*) +([^\s]*) +(.*)$/\1 2021 \3/'` That does not work, I get an error 'sed: No input file`

Comment: @Alex, sure, have edited my code now to take input from a Input_file.

Comment: Thanks. However, I have no ideas how that regex works. Can you describe it in more detail? Where does it match the numbers?

Comment: @Alex, sure I have added detailed explanation for my solution. I am looking by spaces, not by digits, I have also tried to fix your attempt too, let me know if this helps you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232894/discussion-between-alex-and-ravindersingh13).

Comment: @Alex, Sorry I can't join chat room, please comment here, thank you.

Comment: I really would like to catch/match(?) the group with the 4 digits just before the phrase 'alex4200'. Otherwise the year might be added somewhere else when the word 'copyright' is mentioned

Comment: @Alex, sure then `sed -E 's/^(COPYRIGHT\s+\(.*\))\s+([0-9]{4})(.*)$/\1 2021 \3/' file` will work. Once you confirm this I will add it in my answer.